# How to detect symbols for a "rhythm game" auto player

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am developing a "rhythm game" auto playing using Python, but I have a problem.

My plan is as follows.

1 Capture a specific range in the game.(Infinite repeat)

2 "1" to from detect pre-stored pictures.

3 When detected, enter the keyboard "S" button.

"1" was successfully implemented, But I could not implement number "2".

rhythm game = When the red square box is in the white square box, it is a game to input 's' button.

P.S  I'm using python Ver

[image] Capture range

[image] Photos to detect

[image] My code

[image] What is rhythm game ??

Comment: Could you maybe make your description a bit clearer. It sounds very enigmatic to me. Maybe you can also add the code you have so far for "2". And maybe you could add a quick description of what 1 and 2 means in the game for all those, who don't know rythm game.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Are you developing the game, or do you want to program an autoplayer, that plays the game? Does the reaction which is expected by the player, depend on the icon that moves into the capture range? I mean the icon that looks like a loudspeaker in the example you linked.

Comment: Ok I just saw you use a library to grab screen images, so I guess you really program an autoplayer. If there are more symbols, the best way to deal with it, is probably to use machine learning. In this case I guess neural nets would be the best choice. I guess there are not so many variations each symbol is displayed, so I think the neural net doesn't need to be very complex. Probably you can even simply use `sklearn` (e.g. `sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier` with just one hidden layer might be sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect symbols for an autoplayer, you can apply Neural Networks, like supported by sklearn, PyTorch or Keras. The first is a bit easier to handle, but PyTorch and Keras also can use the graphics cards (at least Nvidia) to make training faster, because they support cuda.

If you have say five "lanes" where the symbols move downward, I would try to grab a piece of the same size and relative position from each of the five "lanes" so you would capture a similar part of the symbol for every lane. You then can feed this five parts to your trained net to have it decide whether there is a symbol (and which) or if there is none and then react in your python code based on this decision.

If you can manage to grab a similar area, that would contain a similar piece of the symbol for all lanes, it will be easy to do the job for a neural net and you can thus keep its architecture simple. But as also applying a trained NN (to decide if there is a symbol) takes time, I would

1. keep the net simple, so it has as few neurons as possible (try not to exaggerate with the hidden layers)
2. I would also try to keep the input area as small as possible (so just a fragment large enough to contain a part of the symbol, not the whole symbol) and
3. maybe you can add some fast extra logic, with which you can check, if the input area for a lane is blank (e.g. just contains background color) or if there is something else in the input area, which might be a symobl. So you could avoid some unneccesary work for your NN, which basically is a large number of float operations.

All of this is just meant to make the process faster, because faster means, you can check for symbols with a higher frequency.

To be able to train the net, I would just implement the code, that grabs the input areas of the lanes and the logic I described under 3.) above (if it is possible to implement something like this). This would serve as a frame for your final program with the NN later and you could start with it to grab training images for your net. But you need to label them by hand. That's the boring part of the job. So you look at the grabbed image fragments and save in an extra text file the name of the image and if/which symbol it contains.
If you have problems labelling just small fragments, you can just cheat a bit and make the input area for your job a bit bigger, so it is easier to recognize the symbols and then reduce the size of them if you feed them to the neural net.

Btw. even if it sounds silly to you, you should probably feed a similar ratio of all image types to your NN during training, as they get later when applied. So e.g. if you can't implement a logic like described in 3.) you should also put plenty of images, where there is no symbol in the input area and not just one or two. That's because a NN only learns if it gets enough chances to make mistakes. So if you have say just one image without a symbol in your training data, your NN could misclassify it, but because it is just one image it could be outnumbered by the other pictures and so the net would be almost worthless for an autoplayer.

Ok it is a bit more complicated, this could only happen if adjusting the nets weights to detect blank images correctly would cause the net to be less certain about other fragments of symbols. But it is not unlikely to happen.

Btw. If you choose your input areas in your lanes, I would rather chose rectangler areas that are larger in the vertical direction, than horizontally. If you don't succeed with a regular NN (which I don't think), you can try with a convolutional layer instead. But without need to do so, I wouldn't do it, because it makes the network more complex and thus slower.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think it is the answer to your question, you can mark it as the answer. Please let me know, when you succeeded with the implementation. I guess it will take a while though, but you will learn a lot, you can also use for other purposes, so keep trying until you get your results. It will be worth it.